# How would I move items to the right and left to create a 3 column layout?

Tags: html, css

Working on a project for school a website that needs to be a three column layout. Im having trouble moving the divs to the right and left of the Main  and also displaying them items on the sides stacked. Im supposed to be practicing and using floats, block display, positioning,and clear on this project.

**This is a picture of what I currently have.**
[image: This is a picture of what I currently have.]

**This is how its supposed to look.**
[image: This is how its supposed to look.]

```css
header,
footer,
nav,
div,
p,
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, "Trebuchet MS", "DejuVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(63, 159, 217);
  height: 3em;
}

header .brand {
  font-family: Vendana, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px 20px 12px;
  margin-left: 3em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

header nav {
  margin: 0.70em 1em 0 0;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 60%;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header li {
  padding: 0 1em;
  display: inline;
}

header li a:link {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Main structure */

div#container {}

#main {
  margin: 0 20em 0 16em;
}


/*right side column*/

aside {
  float: right;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0px;
}

#rail {}


/* other common classes */

.well,
.alert {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.well {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  float: left;
}

.well h3 {
  background-color: #b6d1f2;
  padding: 1em;
}

.alert {
  background-color: #edebe1;
  border-color: #e0d9cb;
  color: #817b58;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}


/* main styles */

#main {
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
  margin: 0em 24em 0em 24em;
}

#main h2 {
  padding-top: 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#main h4 {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#main th {
  text-align: left;
}

#main table {}

#main #yourCompany {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  float: left;
}

#main #client {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  float: right;
}

#main hr {
  clear: both;
}

.bigButton {
  margin-top: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(63, 159, 217);
  text-align: center;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* left rail styles */

#rail nav {}

#rail nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

#rail nav ul li {
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}


/* right aside styles */

ul#changeList,
ul#sellersList,
ul#messageList {
  background-color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul#changeList li {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

ul#changeList li p {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

ul#changeList li span {
  min-width: 1.75em;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
  color: #616466;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  float: left;
}

ul#sellersList li,
ul#messageList li {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em 0.25em 0 0;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

ul#sellersList img {
  float: left;
}

ul#sellersList p {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}

ul#messageList img {
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  float: left;
}

#messageList li p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0.3em 0.25em;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chapter 5</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="chapter05-project2.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a class="brand" href="#">Not A Real CRM</a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tasks</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="main">
      <div class="breadcrumb">
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a> / <a href="#">Sales</a>
      </div>
      <h2>Invoice</h2>
      <div id="yourCompany">
        <h4>Pearson Ed Canada</h4>
        26 Prince Andrew Place<br/> Don Mills, Ontario M3C 2T8<br/> 416-447-5101
        <br/> 1-800-263-9965
      </div>
      <div id="client">
        <h4>Martha Silk</h4>
        194A Chain Lake Drive<br/> Halifax, NS B3S 1C5 <br/> +1 (902) 450-0450
      </div>
      <hr>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Author</th>
            <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
            <th scope="col">Year</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="images/book/0321837347.jpg" alt="Precalculus" /></td>
            <td><em>Precalculus</em></td>
            <td>Robert Blitzer</td>
            <td>0321837347</td>
            <td>2014</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="images/book/0321826132.jpg" alt="College Algebra with Modeling & Visualization" /></td>
            <td><em>College Algebra with Modeling & Visualization</em></td>
            <td>Gary Rockswold</td>
            <td>0321826132</td>
            <td>2014</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="images/book/0321826124.jpg" alt="Algebra and Trigonometry with Modeling & Visualization" /></td>
            <td><em>Algebra and Trigonometry with Modeling & Visualization</em></td>
            <td>Gary Rockswold</td>
            <td>0321826124</td>
            <td>2014</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p><a href="#" class="bigButton">Send to Client</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="rail">
      <div class="alert">
        <span class="icon-user"></span>
        <strong>John Locke</strong><br/> Senior Sales Rep<br/>
        <a href="#">Settings</a> | <a href="#">Logout</a>
      </div>
      <nav class="well">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tasks</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="well">
        <h3>Recent Messages</h3>
        <ul id="messageList">
          <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
            <p>From <a href="#">Ellie Sullivan</a><br/>On 4 October, 2014 </p>
          </li>
          <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
            <p>From <a href="#">Madalena Sampaio</a><br/>On 4 October, 2014 </p>
          </li>
          <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
            <p>From <a href="#">Puja Srivastava</a><br/>On 3 October, 2014 </p>
          </li>
          <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
            <p>From <a href="#">Mark Taylor</a><br/>On 2 October, 2014 </p>
          </li>
          <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
            <p>From <a href="#">Madalena Sampaio</a><br/>On 2 October, 2014 </p>
          </li>
          <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
            <p>From <a href="#">Ellie Sullivan</a><br/>On 1 October, 2014 </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <aside>
      <div class="well">
        <h3>Weekly Changes</h3>
        <ul id="changeList">
          <li><span class="changeNumber">20</span>
            <p>New Orders</p>
          </li>
          <li><span class="changeNumber">5</span>
            <p>New Books</p>
          </li>
          <li><span class="changeNumber">6</span>
            <p>New Customers</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <h3>Top Sellers</h3>
        <ul id="sellersList">
          <li>
            <img src="images/book/013261930X.jpg" alt="English                      for Careers" class="blockBook" />
            <p class="blockTitle"><em><a href="#">English for                    Careers</a></em></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="images/book/013267145X.jpg" alt="Adaptive Filter Theory" class="blockBook" />
            <p class="blockTitle"><em><a href="#">Adaptive Filter Theory</a></em></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="images/book/013284737X.jpg" alt="Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis" class="blockBook" />
            <p class="blockTitle"><em><a href="#">Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis</a></em></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="images/book/013286908X.jpg" alt="Ownership Series: Ownership: Critical Thinking" class="blockBook" />
            <p class="blockTitle"><em><a href="#">Ownership Series: Ownership: Critical Thinking</a></em></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="images/book/013295351X.jpg" alt="Opportunities and Challenges of Workplace Diversity" class="blockBook" />
            <p class="blockTitle"><em><a href="#">Opportunities and Challenges of Workplace Diversity</a></em></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you think you could come up with a smaller example code?

Comment: Try CSS flex box https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

To your outer div give this property `display:flex; justify-content:space-between; flex-direction:row;` and your inner div or content will be take margins accordingly .This is the answer for making the one div left and one on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

**I have changed some coding and this is the result, hopefully it can help**

---

> CSS AND HTML

```css
/* Atur Container */
html, body, #app, .appInti {margin: 0 auto;padding: 0 auto;height: 100%;}
/* Atur 3 Warna Utama */
.primarycolor {background-color: #21344C!important;}.text-primarycolor {color: #21344C!important;}
.primarycolor2 {background-color: #f5f5f5!important;}.text-primarycolor2 {color: #f5f5f5 !important;}
.primarycolor3 {background-color: #F7F7F7!important;}.text-primarycolor3 {color: #F7F7F7 !important;}
.primarycolor4 {background-color: #38698B!important;}.text-primarycolor4 {color: #38698B !important;}
/* Atur Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar{width:7px;background:#eee;height: 8px;border: 1px solid #ddd;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color:#575757;border-radius:0px;}
::-moz-scrollbar{width:8px;background:#FFF}
::-moz-scrollbar-thumb{background-color:#575757;border-radius:0px}
/* Atur DragColor */
::selection {background-color: #D5E7F3;color:#0F75BD;}
::-moz-selection {background-color: #D5E7F3;color:#0F75BD;}
::-webkit-selection {background-color: #D5E7F3;color:#0F75BD;}
/*======================================================*/
header,footer,nav,div,p,body {
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, "Trebuchet MS", "DejuVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
/*HEADER==
===========*/
header {
  background-color: rgb(63, 159, 217);
  height: 3em;
}

header .brand {
  font-family: Vendana, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px 20px 12px;
  margin-left: 3em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

header nav {
  padding: 0.70em 1em 0 0;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header li {
  padding: 0 1em;
  display: inline;
}

header li a:link {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Main structure==
===========*/
main{display: block;width: 100%;}
#main {width: 60%;float:left;}
aside {width: 20%;float:left;margin-top: -20px;}
#rail {width: 20%;float:left;}


/*RAIL
===========*/
.w-100{width: 100%;}
.alert {
  background-color: #edebe1;
  border-color: #e0d9cb;
  color: #817b58;
}

/* other common classes */
.alert {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.well{
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.well h3 {
  background-color: #b6d1f2;
  padding: 1em;
}

.breadcrumb {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}


.container{padding: 0 15px;}
/* main styles */

#main {
/*  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;*/
/*  margin: 0em 24em 0em 24em;*/
}

#main h2 {
  padding-top: 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#main h4 {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#main th {
  text-align: left;
}

#main table {}

#main #yourCompany {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  float: left;
}

#main #client {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  float: right;
}

#main hr {
  clear: both;
}

.bigButton {
  margin-top: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(63, 159, 217);
  text-align: center;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* left rail styles */

#rail nav {}

#rail nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

#rail nav ul li {
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}


/* right aside styles */

ul#changeList,
ul#sellersList,
ul#messageList {
  background-color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul#changeList li {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

ul#changeList li p {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

ul#changeList li span {
  min-width: 1.75em;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
  color: #616466;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  float: left;
}

ul#sellersList li,
ul#messageList li {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em 0.25em 0 0;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

ul#sellersList img {
  float: left;
}

ul#sellersList p {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}

ul#messageList img {
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  float: left;
}

#messageList li p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0.3em 0.25em;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chapter 5</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a class="brand" href="#">Not A Real CRM</a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tasks</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="rail">
            <div class="w-100">
                <div class="alert">
                    <span class="icon-user"></span>
                    <strong>John Locke</strong>
                    <br/> Senior Sales Rep
                    <br/>
                    <a href="#">Settings</a> | <a href="#">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.w100-->
            <div class="w-100">
                <nav class="well primarycolor2" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tasks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div><!--/.w100-->
            <div class="w-100">
                <div class="well primarycolor2 alert">
                    <h3>Recent Messages</h3>
                    <ul id="messageList">
                        <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
                            <p>From <a href="#">Ellie Sullivan</a>
                                <br/>On 4 October, 2014 </p>
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
                            <p>From <a href="#">Madalena Sampaio</a>
                                <br/>On 4 October, 2014 </p>
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
                            <p>From <a href="#">Puja Srivastava</a>
                                <br/>On 3 October, 2014 </p>
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
                            <p>From <a href="#">Mark Taylor</a>
                                <br/>On 2 October, 2014 </p>
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
                            <p>From <a href="#">Madalena Sampaio</a>
                                <br/>On 2 October, 2014 </p>
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="images/book/glyphicons_042_group.png" class="blockIcon">
                            <p>From <a href="#">Ellie Sullivan</a>
                                <br/>On 1 October, 2014 </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>    
            </div><!--/.w100-->
            
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="breadcrumb">
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a> / <a href="#">Sales</a>
                </div>
                <h2>Invoice</h2>
                <div id="yourCompany">
                    <h4>Pearson Ed Canada</h4> 26 Prince Andrew Place
                    <br/> Don Mills, Ontario M3C 2T8
                    <br/> 416-447-5101
                    <br/> 1-800-263-9965
                </div>
                <div id="client">
                    <h4>Martha Silk</h4> 194A Chain Lake Drive
                    <br/> Halifax, NS B3S 1C5
                    <br/> +1 (902) 450-0450
                </div>
                <hr>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th scope="col">Title</th>
                            <th scope="col">Author</th>
                            <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
                            <th scope="col">Year</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="images/book/0321837347.jpg" alt="Precalculus" /></td>
                            <td><em>Precalculus</em></td>
                            <td>Robert Blitzer</td>
                            <td>0321837347</td>
                            <td>2014</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="images/book/0321826132.jpg" alt="College Algebra with Modeling & Visualization" /></td>
                            <td><em>College Algebra with Modeling & Visualization</em></td>
                            <td>Gary Rockswold</td>
                            <td>0321826132</td>
                            <td>2014</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="images/book/0321826124.jpg" alt="Algebra and Trigonometry with Modeling & Visualization" /></td>
                            <td><em>Algebra and Trigonometry with Modeling & Visualization</em></td>
                            <td>Gary Rockswold</td>
                            <td>0321826124</td>
                            <td>2014</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <p><a href="#" class="bigButton">Send to Client</a></p>
            </div><!--/.container-->
        </div><!--/#main-->
        <aside>
            <div class="well">
                <h3>Weekly Changes</h3>
                <ul id="changeList">
                    <li><span class="changeNumber">20</span>
                        <p>New Orders</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="changeNumber">5</span>
                        <p>New Books</p>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="changeNumber">6</span>
                        <p>New Customers</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="well">
                <h3>Top Sellers</h3>
                <ul id="sellersList">
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/book/013261930X.jpg" alt="English                      for Careers" class="blockBook" />
                        <p class="blockTitle"><em><a href="#">English for                    Careers</a></em></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/book/013267145X.jpg" alt="Adaptive Filter Theory" class="blockBook" />
                        <p class="blockTitle"><em><a href="#">Adaptive Filter Theory</a></em></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/book/013284737X.jpg" alt="Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis" class="blockBook" />
                        <p class="blockTitle"><em><a href="#">Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis</a></em></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/book/013286908X.jpg" alt="Ownership Series: Ownership: Critical Thinking" class="blockBook" />
                        <p class="blockTitle"><em><a href="#">Ownership Series: Ownership: Critical Thinking</a></em></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/book/013295351X.jpg" alt="Opportunities and Challenges of Workplace Diversity" class="blockBook" />
                        <p class="blockTitle"><em><a href="#">Opportunities and Challenges of Workplace Diversity</a></em></p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to make three columns you also can use display table concept like this.

```css
header{
height:25px;
background:#ccc;
}

.div-table{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.cell1,.cell2,.cell3{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
  min-height:500px;
}
.cell1,.cell3{
  width:10%;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.cell2{
width:80%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
  <p>menu</p>
  </header>
    <div class="div-table">
  <div class="cell1">
  <h2>nav goes here</h2></div>
  <div class="cell2">
  <h1>Main Content</h1></div>
  <div class="cell3">
  <h3>Aside goes here</h3></div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can place your three parts of code in respective cells

ex left nav in cell1
middle part that is main in cell2 
and aside in cell3;

you can give width acordingly